# Turning two lists into 1 without tuples involved

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumerate

I have two lists and am trying to use zip in a weird way to make them one list. I have a list of names, say

```
names = ['nathan', 'julian', 'ramy', 'jack']
```

and a list of occurrences from the previous context. Lets say this list is something like `['2', '3', '4', '5']`. This is the number of times each name appeared in the list... Now how would i get something like `['nathan 2', 'julian 3', 'ramy 4', 'jack 5']` using the zip function? Doesn't HAVE to use the zip function but I thought that that would be the only way to do it using the functions that I know of.

Answer (score 5):

```
[" ".join(pair) for pair in zip(names, occurences)]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
map(" ".join, zip(names, occurrences))
```

@David Robinson's answer might be slightly more Pythonic (IIRC Guido strongly prefers list comprehensions to filter/map), but this is shorter.  Credit to him for the `" ".join` idea though.